# How do I update data that has its its primary key set to IsIdentity?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

In the following code the command executes but update doesn't take place. The main issue is the 
primary which is **IDNumber** is set to **IsIdentity** in the SQL Server database. I'd be thankful if someone could help me out.

```
If rbnCore.Checked = True Then
                    subject = "Core"
                Else : subject = "Elective"
                End If
 qry = "Update ProgramDetails.Subjects set SubjectCode=@SubjectCode,SubjectName=@SubjectName,SubjectType=@SubjectType,UserID=@UserID,Password=@Password where IDNumber='" & txtIDNumber.Text & "'"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectCode", txtSubjectCode.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectName", txtSubName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectType", subject))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUserName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                showgrid()
            End If
```

Comment: check the value of 'txtIDNumber.Text' and check same value will be exists in database or not

Comment: Remember that the update will be successful even if it updates no rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you absolutely want to have IDNumber passed in as a parameter as well to help protect against SQL injection attacks (just add a new param and change code to where IDNumber=@IDNumber)

You can easily see if an update occurred or not by examining the result of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() - it returns the number of rows affected, and will obviously be zero if nothing happened.

```
If rbnCore.Checked = True Then
                    subject = "Core"
                Else : subject = "Elective"
                End If
 qry = "Update ProgramDetails.Subjects set SubjectCode=@SubjectCode,SubjectName=@SubjectName,SubjectType=@SubjectType,UserID=@UserID,Password=@Password where IDNumber=@IDNumber"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@IDNumber", txtIDNumber.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectCode", txtSubjectCode.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectName", txtSubName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectType", subject))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUserName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
                If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                  MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                  showgrid()
                Else
                  'nothing affected...
                End If
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a .Net environment? Why do your strings use '&' for concatenation instead of '+'. Check that. So, rewrite your query as:
 qry = "Update ProgramDetails.Subjects set   SubjectCode=@SubjectCode,SubjectName=@SubjectName,SubjectType=@SubjectType,UserID=@UserID,Pass word=@Password where IDNumber='" + txtIDNumber.Text + "'"

Comment: In VB.Net, & is the string concatenation operator, not +